# Match Phone Number from Sheet Cell Value to Google Contacts and get Full name and Address

Tags: google-apps-script

It's my first question, I am feeling nervous.

Here, I am trying to get Customer Full name and address from google contacts. But it's not working. Looking for experts help

```
function importContact() {
   var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "Stock" ) { 
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    var phone = r.getValue()
  if( r.getColumn() == 10 ) {
      var nextCell1 = r.offset(0, 1);
      var nextCell2 = r.offset(0, 2);
      var contacts = ContactsApp.getContactsByPhone(phone,'Other');
   for(var i = 0, iLen = contacts.length; i < iLen; i++) {
    var fullname = contacts[i].getFullName();
    var address = contacts[i].getAddresses(ContactsApp.Field.HOME_ADDRESS);
    if(fullname) {
       nextCell1.setValue(fullname);
       nextCell2.setValue(address);
    } else {
       nextCell1.setValue('New Customer');
    }
  }  
}
}
}
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Did you run the debugger? Are you having issues with leading 0's maybe? did you check how you need to change the numbers to have them match?

Comment: After running the code, choose the "View" menu, and then select "Execution Transcript."  At the bottom, it states whether the code completed or not.  If it did not complete, it will state what line the code failed on.  Information like that will help us.  Also, click the following link and read the [troubleshooting guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting)  Or, from the code editor, choose "Help" and then "Documentation" and search "trouble"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution #1 did not seem to fully work, so debugged and amended until:

- it did confirm the "new customer" event, and
- worked for addresses.

Tried to comment Cooper's one, but do not have enough reputation. Hope this is ok, and am ready to erase my reply if needed.

A few notes on the code:

- it assumes that any contact has a name field, but it might not be always true;
- it checks if the address fields exists though, because it is way more likely to be empty than name field;
- in case address does not exist code enters N.A. in the address cell;
- `var address = addresses[0].getAddress()`  was the main missing link in the first solution, apparently;
- users other than the original questioner should replace "Stock" in `if( s.getName() == "Stock" )` with appropriate Sheet Name.

As should be obvious, by now: I am a learner, not an expert. Any suggestion to improve is more than welcome.

```js
function importContact() 
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "Stock" )
  { 
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    var phone = r.getValue();
    if( r.getColumn() == 1 ) 
    {
      var nextCell1 = r.offset(0, 1);
      var nextCell2 = r.offset(0, 2);
      var contacts = ContactsApp.getContactsByPhone(phone);
      if(contacts.length == 0) 
      {
        nextCell1.setValue('New Customer');        
      }
      else 
      {
        for(var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) 
        {
          var fullname = contacts[i].getFullName();
          nextCell1.setValue(fullname);
          var addresses = contacts[i].getAddresses(ContactsApp.Field.HOME_ADDRESS);
          if (addresses.length == 0) 
          {
            nextCell2.setValue("Not Available");
          }
          else
          {
            var address = addresses[0].getAddress() //this was the missing link in the first solution, apparently
            nextCell2.setValue(address);
          }
        }
      }
     }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your great help! It worked for me!

Comment: Awesome, happy to hear that :)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for me.  But I don't have addresses for any contacts so I can't verify that.

```
function importContact() 
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "Stock" ) 
  { 
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    var phone = r.getValue();
    if( r.getColumn() == 1 ) 
    {
      var nextCell1 = r.offset(0, 1);
      var nextCell2 = r.offset(0, 2);
      var contacts = ContactsApp.getContactsByPhone(phone);
      for(var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) 
      {
        var fullname = contacts[i].getFullName();
        var address = contacts[i].getAddresses();
        if(fullname) 
        {
           nextCell1.setValue(fullname);
           nextCell2.setValue(address);
        } 
        else 
        {
           nextCell1.setValue('New Customer');
        }
      }  
    }
  }
}
```